# Wdproj won't open

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wdproj

I just switched to Windows7 Professional 64 bit from Vista Ultimate 32 bit.  I reinstalled all Visual Studio 2008 Professional and applied SP1.  All is working well except I can't open a solution that contains a **wdproj** file.  I found this [link](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/70/350939.aspx) (and a bunch of others scraped from Microsoft) with a similar problem.  They suggested using calling "devenv.exe /setup", "devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates" and "devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs".  Any idea what I should do?

[alt text http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/1223/erroryu.png](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/1223/erroryu.png)

Comment: what parts of visual studio did you install ? I would expect wd package to only be installed if you pick the web development tools...

Comment: I tried reinstalling and checking all the boxes, the only one I hadn't checked the previous time was one a couple of layers under C++.  Should I install Web Developer Express?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out I needed to install [this msi](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en).  One of my coworkers reminded me.

Comment: The MSI is named "Visual Studio® 2008 Web Deployment Projects - RTW", in case the link above might someday change.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the installer for VS2010 as well: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24509